# How to create new User with password on MongoDB and connect from NodeJS application

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I need some help with setting up my NodeJS application to connect with the MongoDB with credentials.

I'm confused with creating user on the `admin` database, or on the database I will store my documents, and then connecting to it from my application.

So, let's say I have this MongoDB service running on `localhost` port `27017` and my database is called `myAmazingApp`. I want to create a user with Read/Write permissions on this now empty database and set user `userApp` and password `passwordApp`.

I'm using `Mongoose` on NodeJS.

My question includes where and how I must create this User/Role/whatever on MongoDB.

By the way, right now this is my connection string

`mongodb://userApp:passwordApp@localhost:27017/myAmazingApp` and I am connecting with `mongoose.connect`.

It gives me **Authentication failed**

Comment: please paste the file where you have your `mongoose.connect()` going on. After that, paste your `authentication.js` file and your `user.js` model file.

Answer (score 2):

1. Log into the mongo shell via terminal

```
user@ubuntu:~$ mongo
```

and switch to admin DB

```
> use admin
```

2. Create a user with the "userAdminAnyDatabase" role, which grants the privilege to create other users on any existing database.

```
> db.createUser(
  {
    user: "adminUser",
    pwd: "adminPwd",
    roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ]
  }
)
```

3. Disconnect from the mongo shell
4. You need to enable authentication in mongod configuration file. Open /etc/mongod.conf or /etc/mongodb.conf

```
security:
    authorization: "disabled"
```

change it to

```
security:
    authorization: "enabled"
```

5. Restart mongodb service

```
user@ubuntu:~$ sudo service mongodb restart
```

or

```
user@ubuntu:~$ sudo service mongod restart
```

6. Connect and authenticate as the user administrator

```
user@ubuntu:~$ mongo admin
> db.auth("adminUser", "adminPwd")
1
```

7. Create additional users as needed

```
> use myAmazingApp
> db.createUser(
  {
    user: "userApp",
    pwd: "passwordApp",
    roles: [ { role: "readWrite", db: "myAmazingApp" } ]
  }
)
```

8. While connecting mongoose you can pass it in the connection URI or as options

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://userApp:passwordApp@localhost:27017/myAmazingApp');
```

or

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/myAmazingApp', {useNewUrlParser: true, user: "userApp", pass: "user:passwordApp"});
```